# Python and Flask, display data out of mysql DB on html page

Tags: python, mysql, flask

every time I try to display my data out of my MySQL database on a `html` page it will only show the first column of the record or only the name of the column itself.

For example:

MyDatabase

db

```
id  names
1   Harry
2   Snape
```

main.py

```
@app.route("/db", methodes = ["POST", "GET"])
def db():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("SELECT names FROM db WHERE id = 1")
        output = cur.fetchone()
        cur. close 
        return render_template("db.html", data = output)
    else:
        return render_template("db.html")
```

db.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}db{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="show data">
</form>

<!-- Output 1 -->
<p>{{data}}</p>

<!-- Output 2 -->
{% for i in data %}
    <p>{{i}}</p>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Output 3 -->
{% for i in data %}
    <p>{{i[0]}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Output 1 = {'names': 'Harry'}

Output 2 = names

Output 3 = n

I just want to get the records, not the column name, how can I do this (*Output = Harry*)

I am new to all this, I would be happy about a short explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me

db.html

```
<p>{{data.names}}</p>
```

main.py

```
else:
    return render_template("db.html", data = "")
```

This is to avoid getting the error that "data" is undefined when restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

you can search for Dictionary in Python .

here is some changes in your db.html code :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}db{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="show data">
</form>

<!-- Output 1 -->
<p>{{data['names']}}</p>

<!-- Output 2 -->
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
    <p>{{value}}</p>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```